# how to get aws apigateway stage info for v2 in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am looking a way to get stage info via aws cli for apigatewayv2, for restapi I can use the following command and it works fine

```
 aws apigateway get-stages --rest-api-id $APIID  --profile int  --query  'item[?stageName==`current`]'  --output json
```

since the stackresource is of "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi" type,
I am trying to get same command running for Httpapi which is in apigateway version 2 "AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api" and it does not work as it gives the error

```
An error occurred (NotFoundException) when calling the GetStages operation: Invalid API identifier specified
```

since this is not restapi and is of v2 I think I need to change something on --rest-api-id $APIID  but could not find any doc, wondering if aws supports v2 in cli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `aws apigatewayv2 get-stages --api-id <>  --profile <>`

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. We should rather explain the challenge, and how our solution tackles it.